# How to remove setTimeout function when ajax return 1?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I created `getAbsentMember` to do some query at the time 8 am(office time) and greater than 9 am for late users.I used setTimeout function to check hours.But I want to do in second condition (greater than 9) is first to check current user exists in database,so its return 1 if exist,0 not.The problem is `how to remove setTimeout function if return 1(existed)`.

```
function getAbsentMember() {
var x = new Date();
var h = x.getHours();
var m = x.getMinutes();
var s  = x.getSeconds();
if (h === 8 && m === 0 && s === 0) {
    addAbsent();
}
else if(h > 9) {
    $.ajax({
        url : "checkingurl",
        type : "GET",
        dataType : "json",
        success : function (c) {
            if(c) {return false;}//how to remove setTimeout function[here]
            else  { addAbsent();}
        }
    });
}    
setTimeout(function(){
    getAbsentMember();
},1000);
}
getAbsentMember();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can turn difficult to handle all the cases, a easier approach could be to add the timeout only if required

```
function getAbsentMember() {
  var x = new Date();
  var h = x.getHours();
  var m = x.getMinutes();
  var s = x.getSeconds();
  if (h === 8 && m === 0 && s === 0) {
    addAbsent();
    setTimeout(getAbsentMember, 1000);
  } else if (h > 9) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "checkingurl",
      type: "GET",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(c) {
        if (c) {
          return false;
        } //how to remove setTimeout function[here]
        else {
          addAbsent();
          setTimeout(getAbsentMember, 1000);
        }
      }
    }).fail(function() {
      setTimeout(getAbsentMember, 1000);
    });
  }
}
getAbsentMember();
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `clearTimeout()` to remove `setTimeout`

```
var fn =setTimeout(function(){
    getAbsentMember();
},1000);

if(/*your condition*/){
    clearTimeout(fn);
}
```

Comment: @David Jawphan, You may also use setTimeout conditionally like in failure to avoid un-necessary calls.

Answer (score 1):

Try this add timeOut when required

```
function getAbsentMember() {
  var x = new Date();
  var h = x.getHours();
  var m = x.getMinutes();
  var s = x.getSeconds();
  if (h === 8 && m === 0 && s === 0) {
    addAbsent();
    setTimeout(getAbsentMember, 1000);
  } else if (h > 9) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "checkingurl",
      type: "GET",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(result) {
        if (result!=1) {
          addAbsent();
          setTimeout(getAbsentMember, 1000);
        }
      }
    }).fail(function() {
      setTimeout(getAbsentMember, 1000);
    });
  }
}
getAbsentMember();
```